await Promise.all is not working as expect in a for-loop in nodejs
I got the correct print result, but the print time was not as expected, and my expected result was about one log every second in nodejs
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Promise 1'));
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Promise 2'));
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Promise 3'));
const promise4 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Promise 4'));
const promise5 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Promise 5'));
const promise6 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Promise 5'));
const promise7 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Promise 7'));
const promise8 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Promise 8'));
const promise9 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Promise 9'));
const promise10 = new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000, 'Promise 10'));

const promiseArrays = [
    [promise1, promise2],
    [promise3, promise4],
    [promise5, promise6],
    [promise7, promise8],
    [promise3, promise4],
    [promise9],
    [promise10]
];

async function inOrder() {
    
    for (const promiseArray of promiseArrays) {
        const res = await Promise.all(promiseArray)
        console.log(res.join(""))

        if (res.join("") === 'Promise 9') {
            break
        }
    }
}

inOrder()

I got the correct print result, but the print time was not as expected, and my expected result was about one log every second in nodejs

All of your timers start at almost exactly the same time, and will all fire 1000 milliseconds after that.

Sorry, misread your code - however, you've fallen for the misconception that Promsie.all somehow "executes" Promises - no - new Promise is when the executor code runs

@Pointy Doesn't await Promise.all work here?

To get the results you expect, you'd write the code like this fiddle

@jinwu it does, but what Promise.all() does is wait for existing promises to resolve.  Your timers all start when you create the initial Promise objects. That's why they all start at almost exactly the same time.

Once you wait for the first batch, the rest of them will be finished at almost the same time.

@JaromandaX I'm sorry, I forgot to mention it. the code runs in nodejs v18.14.1

@jinwu - irrelevant - the code in the fiddle will run exactly the same in nodejs as it does in the browser - your issue is an all too common misunderstanding of what Promise.all does - read the documentation

@JaromandaX I switched versions of nodejs to run in v20 and didn't get the expected results

@JaromandaX Again, when I run this code in the browser console, I don't get the expected results

really @jinwu? the fiddle outputs Promise1Promise2 a second later Promise 3Promise 4 another second later Promise 5Promise 6 another second later Promise 7Promise 8 another second later Promise 3Promise 4 and finally, another second later Promise 9 .... what were you actually expecting? Note: the code from the fiddle also outputs as above in node ... so, clearly your description of what you expected is wrong. Please clarify exactly what you expected to happen

@JaromandaX You can copy the code and run it directly into the browser console. The execution is different from what you do with a fiddle

uh yeah ... I never said your code works like you want it to work, I said your code is written with the all too common misunderstanding of what Promise.all does - as I already mentioned ... if you want code that behaves like you want it to behave, use the code in the fiddle ... I can't make it any clearer than that

@Pointy I got it,thanks

@JaromandaX sorry, my english is poor. now, i know what you mean...
